# Flowtype interface method that return nothing

Tags: javascript, flowtype

This is a flowtype interface that works properly.

```
export interface StorageLocalInterface {
  setData (key: string, value: string | number): ?string;
  getData (key: string): string | number;
  removeData (key: string): ?string;
}
```

but

```
setData, removeData
```

don't return anything, so I want to achive somthing similar:

```
export interface StorageLocalInterface {
  setData (key: string, value: string | number);
  getData (key: string): string | number;
  removeData (key: string);
}
```

but I get the error: "Unexpected token ;"
Is it possible to make an interface with methods that don't return anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the return type `void`.

```
export interface StorageLocalInterface {
   setData (key: string, value: string | number): void;
   getData (key: string): string | number;
   removeData (key: string): void;
}
```